# How to do "responsive" design in javafx?

Tags: javafx, responsive-design, fxml, screen-resolution

I've got some troubles with javafx.

I've got a FXML file with two tables views and text fields above each and between them.

This FXML is included in another FXML, in a tabPane.

The app is a big application, with many fxmls and includes inside.

So i can't bind my fxml with the scene.

The issue comes with the height of the view.

In my FXML's "**row constraints**" the sum of all percent of them is **100**, but the visual is not good, there is an overflow with **small resolutions like 1360x768**.

I solved the issue with a **scrollPane** and the option "**AS_Needed**", but i don't understand why my tableviews are not reduced when the screen is small.

For example :

the row of the tableview is : `<RowConstraints percentHeight="20"/>`
if i put the value 15 instead of 20 the tableview is reduced. But The sum of all Row Constraints isn't 100 anymore. And if i keep 20, there is an overflow...

Does anybody have a solution ?

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import fr.sdgib.app.tools.* ?>

<GridPane fx:id="gp" alignment="TOP_CENTER" styleClass="gpDetails" gridLinesVisible="true" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxController">
    <children>

        <Label styleClass="lblSousTitre" text="Contrats : " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

        <Label text="Recherche :" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
        <TextField fx:id="tfRechercheContrat" promptText="Recherche" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" onKeyPressed="#rechercherContrat"/>

        <TableView fx:id="tvContrat" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colNum" text="NUMERO DE CONTRAT"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colMontantFixe" text="MONTANT FIXE"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colMontant" text="MONTANT"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colType" text="TYPE"/>
            </columns>
        </TableView>


        <GridPane fx:id="gpFormContrat" gridLinesVisible="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" visible="true" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
            <children>

                <Label text="Type : " GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
                <ComboBox fx:id="cbxType" styleClass="cbxFiche" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" disable="true"/>

                <Label text="xxx : " GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
                <ComboBox fx:id="cbxxxx" styleClass="cbx" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="0" disable="true"/>

                <Label fx:id="lblMontant1" text="Montant xxx: " GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
                <TextFieldLimited fx:id="tfMontant1" maxlength="200" promptText="Montant " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" disable="true"/>

                <Label fx:id="lblMontant 2" text="Montant xxx : " GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
                <TextFieldLimited fx:id="tfMontant2" maxlength="200" promptText="Montant 2" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

                <Label fx:id="lblErrorContrat" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="5"/>

                <Button fx:id="btnSupprimerContrat" styleClass="btnSupprimer" text="SUPPRIMER" visible="true" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="3" disable="true" onAction="#supprimerContrat"/>
                <Button fx:id="btnValiderContrat"  styleClass="btnValider" text="VALIDER" visible="true" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="3" disable="true" onAction="#validerContrat"/>

            </children>
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="20"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="28"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="2"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="20"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="30"/>
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
            </rowConstraints>
        </GridPane>


        <Label styleClass="lblSousTitre" text="Contrats disponibles : " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

        <Label text="Recherche :" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>
        <TextField fx:id="tfRechercheContratDispo" promptText="Recherche" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" onKeyPressed="#rechercherContratDispo"/>

        <TableView fx:id="tvContratDispo" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colNumDispo" text="NUMERO DE CONTRAT"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colMontantFixeDispo" text="MONTANT FIXE"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colMontantDispo" text="MONTANT"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colTypeDispo" text="TYPE"/>
            </columns>
        </TableView>


    </children>
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="5" />
        <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="10" />
        <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="80" />
        <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="5" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="5" />
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="5" />
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="30" />
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="22" />
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="5" />
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="5" />
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="26" />
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="2" />
    </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

here 1368x768 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSgeN.jpg 
and 1920x1080 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZxMK.jpg

Comment: It should "just work". Post a [MCVE] that shows the issue.

Comment: i've just edited my post